# Redis Write Behind and Aside cache strategy

Tags: node.js, caching, redis

I want to implement a write-behind and cache aside strategy at the same time. Basically, I want to read data from the cache if it exists in the cache otherwise fetch data from the database and set it to cache so can I read the same data from cache in next request.

I also want to functionality when anyone wants to update data first update cache data then after a time(eg. every 2 mints) cache automatically update the database.
I don't know which redis function can do this for me, can anybody give me a proper resource. If you tell me all code with this functionality it will be so helpful for me.

I did a lot of google, All are telling the strategy of write-behind and cache aside. But not anybody is telling me proper code and function which i  will use for write back/behind cache in Node JS.

**For this application, I am using node js.**

**Thanks A lot!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following project that uses RedisGears (https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/) to implement write-behind and write-through on Redis.
https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync

Comment: This  project in python but i need in nodejs

Comment: Its a server side python, it's running inside Redis using RedisGears, your client-side can still be nodejs